# Вторая функция не учитывает изменения образованные первой

Tags: jquery

1-й Скрипт изменяет все аккорды в песне

2-й выводит картинки каждого аккорда при наведении

как правильно прописать условия что бы 2-1 учитывал изменения 1-го и выводил картинки соответственно

```js
/*!
 * transposer
 */
(function($) {
 
  $.fn.transpose = function(options) {
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.transpose.defaults, options);
    
    var currentKey = null;
    
    var keys = [
      { name: 'Ab',  value: 0,   type: 'F' },
      { name: 'A',   value: 1,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'A#',  value: 2,   type: 'S' },
      { name: 'Bb',  value: 2,   type: 'F' },
      { name: 'B',   value: 3,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'C',   value: 4,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'C#',  value: 5,   type: 'S' },
      { name: 'Db',  value: 5,   type: 'F' },
      { name: 'D',   value: 6,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'D#',  value: 7,   type: 'S' },
      { name: 'Eb',  value: 7,   type: 'F' },
      { name: 'E',   value: 8,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'F',   value: 9,   type: 'N' },
      { name: 'F#',  value: 10,  type: 'S' },
      { name: 'Gb',  value: 10,  type: 'F' },
      { name: 'G',   value: 11,  type: 'N' },
      { name: 'G#',  value: 0,   type: 'S' }
    ];
  
    var getKeyByName = function (name) {
        if (name.charAt(name.length-1) == "m") {
          name = name.substring(0, name.length-1);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            if (name == keys[i].name) {
                return keys[i];
            }
        }
    };

    var getChordRoot = function (input) {
        if (input.length > 1 && (input.charAt(1) == "b" || input.charAt(1) == "#"))
            return input.substr(0, 2);
        else
            return input.substr(0, 1);
    };

    var getNewKey = function (oldKey, delta, targetKey) {
        var keyValue = getKeyByName(oldKey).value + delta;

        if (keyValue > 11) {
            keyValue -= 12;
        } else if (keyValue < 0) {
            keyValue += 12;
        }
        
        var i=0;
        if (keyValue == 0 || keyValue == 2 || keyValue == 5 || keyValue == 7 || keyValue == 10) {
            // Return the Flat or Sharp Key
            switch(targetKey.name) {
              case "A":
              case "A#":
              case "B":
              case "C":
              case "C#":
              case "D":
              case "D#":
              case "E":
              case "F#":
              case "G":
              case "G#":
                  for (;i<keys.length;i++) {
                    if (keys[i].value == keyValue && keys[i].type == "S") {
                      return keys[i];
                    }
                  }
              default:
                  for (;i<keys.length;i++) {
                    if (keys[i].value == keyValue && keys[i].type == "F") {
                      return keys[i];
                    }
                  }
            }
        }
        else {
            // Return the Natural Key
            for (;i<keys.length;i++) {
              if (keys[i].value == keyValue) {
                return keys[i];
              }
            }
        }
    };

    var getChordType = function (key) {
        switch (key.charAt(key.length - 1)) {
            case "b":
                return "F";
            case "#":
                return "S";
            default:
              return "N";
        }
    };

    var getDelta = function (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        if (oldIndex > newIndex)
            return 0 - (oldIndex - newIndex);
        else if (oldIndex < newIndex)
            return 0 + (newIndex - oldIndex);
        else
            return 0;
    };

    var transposeSong = function (target, key) {
        var newKey = getKeyByName(key);

        if (currentKey.name == newKey.name) {
          return;
        }

        var delta = getDelta(currentKey.value, newKey.value);
        
        $("a.chord", target).each(function (i, el) {
            transposeChord(el, delta, newKey);
        });
        
        currentKey = newKey;
    };

    var transposeChord = function (selector, delta, targetKey) {
        var el = $(selector);
        var oldChord = el.text();
        var oldChordRoot = getChordRoot(oldChord);
        var newChordRoot = getNewKey(oldChordRoot, delta, targetKey);
        var newChord = newChordRoot.name + oldChord.substr(oldChordRoot.length);
        el.text(newChord);

        var sib = el[0].nextSibling;
        if (sib && sib.nodeType == 3 && sib.nodeValue.length > 0 && sib.nodeValue.charAt(0) != "/") {
            var wsLength = getNewWhiteSpaceLength(oldChord.length, newChord.length, sib.nodeValue.length);
            sib.nodeValue = makeString(" ", wsLength);
        }
    };

    var getNewWhiteSpaceLength = function (a, b, c) {
        if (a > b)
            return (c + (a - b));
        else if (a < b)
            return (c - (b - a));
        else
            return c;
    };

    var makeString = function (s, repeat) {
        var o = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < repeat; i++) o.push(s);
        return o.join("");
    }
    
    
    var isChordLine = function (input) {
        var tokens = input.replace(/\s+/, " ").split(" ");

        // Try to find tokens that aren't chords
        // if we find one we know that this line is not a 'chord' line.
        for (var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            if (!$.trim(tokens[i]).length == 0 && !tokens[i].match(opts.chordRegex))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    };
    
     var wrapChords = function (input) {  
        return input.replace(opts.chordReplaceRegex, "<a class='chord'>$1</a>");
        $("a.chord", wrapChords).mouseover(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          newChord($this, $(this).text() == "Dm");
          $(".chord").removeClass("chord");
          $(this).addClass("akk13");
          return false;
      });
  };
  
    return $(this).each(function() {
    
      var startKey = $(this).attr("data-key");
      if (!startKey || $.trim(startKey) == "") {
        startKey = opts.key;
      }

      if (!startKey || $.trim(startKey) == "") {
        throw("Starting key not defined.");
        return this;
      }
      
      currentKey = getKeyByName(startKey);

      // Build tranpose links ===========================================
      var keyLinks = [];
      $(keys).each(function(i, key) {
          if (currentKey.name == key.name)
              keyLinks.push("<a href='#' class='selected'>" + key.name + "</a>");
          else
              keyLinks.push("<a href='#'>" + key.name + "</a>");
      });


      var $this = $(this);
      var keysHtml = $("<div class='transpose-keys'></div>");
      keysHtml.html(keyLinks.join(""));
      $("a", keysHtml).click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          transposeSong($this, $(this).text());
          $(".transpose-keys a").removeClass("selected");
          $(this).addClass("selected");
          return false;
      });
      
      $(this).before(keysHtml);

      var output = [];
      var lines = $(this).text().split("\n");
      var line, tmp = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
          line = lines[i];

          if (isChordLine(line))
              output.push("<span>" + wrapChords(line) + "</span>");
          else
              output.push("<span>" + line + "</span>");
      };

      $(this).html(output.join("\n"));
    });
  };

  $.fn.transpose.defaults = {
    chordRegex: /^[A-G][b\#]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7\#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim7|m\/maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|sus2|sus4|sus)*(\/[A-G][b\#]*)*$/,
    chordReplaceRegex: /([A-G][b\#]?(2|5|6|7|9|11|13|6\/9|7\-5|7\-9|7\#5|7\#9|7\+5|7\+9|7b5|7b9|7sus2|7sus4|add2|add4|add9|aug|dim|dim7|m\/maj7|m6|m7|m7b5|m9|m11|m13|maj7|maj9|maj11|maj13|mb5|m|sus2|sus4|sus)*)/g
  };

})

(jQuery);
```

```css
/*!
 * Chord Transposer
 */
span.c { 
  font-weight: bold; 
  color: #d32735;
}

.transpose-keys {
 font-weight: bold; 
 margin: 10px 0;
 overflow: auto;
 font: 22pt;
}
.transpose-keys a { 
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 2.50em;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 .25em .25em 0;
 color: #333;
 background: #eee;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: .4em 0;
 border: solid 2px transparent;
 outline: none;
}
.transpose-keys a.selected { 
  background: #01c9e0; 
  color: #FFF;
}

.akk1:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/C.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk2:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk3:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/C7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk4:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/C2.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk5:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk6:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cmaj7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk7:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Csus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk8:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cdi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk9:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cdim.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk10:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cdi7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk11:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Cdim7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk12:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/D.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk13:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk14:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/D7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk15:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk16:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Dsus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk17:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ddi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk18:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ddim.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk19:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ddi7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk20:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Ddim7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk21:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/E.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk22:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Em.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk23:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/E7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk24:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Em7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk25:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Esus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk26:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/F.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk27:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk28:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/F7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk29:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk30:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fmaj7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk31:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fdi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk32:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fdim.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk33:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Fdim7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk34:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/F-C.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk35:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/F-G.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk36:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/F-A.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk37:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/G.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk38:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk39:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/G7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk40:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk41:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/G-Fdi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk42:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/G-H.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk43:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gsus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk44:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gdi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk45:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gdim.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk46:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Gdim7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk47:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/A.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk48:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Am.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk49:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/A7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk50:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Am7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk51:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/A2.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk52:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Asus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk53:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/A-Fdi.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk54:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Amaj7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk55:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/B.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk56:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Bm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk57:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/B7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk58:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Bm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk59:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/B2.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk60:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Bsus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk61:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/H.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk62:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Hm.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk63:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/H7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk64:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Hm7.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
.akk65:hover:after { content: url(http://xn--80aimgum.xn--j1amh/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/Hsus.png); position: absolute; margin-top: -75px; margin-left: -15px; z-index: 9999; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.transposer.css" />
   </head>
<body style="margin: 30px">
  <pre data-key="A">
       A              G                 Am          F
When I find myself in times of trouble, Mother Mary comes to me
B                 G              F   C/E   Dm   C
Speaking words of wisdom, let it be

    A             Gm                Am                F
And in my hour of darkness, She is standing right in front of me
A                 G              F   C/E   Dm   C
Speaking words of wisdom, let it be

       Am         G          F          C
Let it be, let it be, let it be, let it be
                 G              F   C/E   Dm   C
Whisper words of wisdom, let it be
  </pre>

   <script type="text/javascript" src="transposer.js"></script>  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  
$(function() {
     $("pre").transpose();
    
   $(function() {
 $('a.chord').addClass (function(index, currentClass){
    var addedClass;
    if ($(this).text() == "Dm") {
      addedClass = "akk13";
    }
    return addedClass;
  });
});
});
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "первый скрипт" вижу как работатет, а больше ничего не вижу.

Comment: на аккорд "Dm" наведите

Comment: ничего не происходит у меня куда ни наводи

Comment: 301й редирект там по кругу начинает бегать у картинки

Comment: Это  основная проблема? Как поправить?

Comment: я откуда знаю проблема это у вас или нет. это приводит к тому, что у меня картинка не отображается вообще никакая.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/k31p74 странно у меня отображается